# French (?) pastry on the cover of a book

Tags: food-identification, pastry

Georges Lefebvre's "The French Revolution" has this lovely pastry on its cover (see below).Does anyone know what this is and how to make it?

[image: The cover of the book "The French Revolution", by Georges Lefebvre]

Comment: It's hard to be sure, but it looks like a *tarte au citron* or lemon curd tart. Recipe requests are off topic, but you should be able to find plenty of them online.

Comment: Alan: you should put that in as an answer

Comment: @alanmunn - It might be general recipe requests are too broad, but if they’re asking for a specific persons specific recipe (ie, lefebvre’s lemon tart recipe in this book only, instead of “any good” lemon tart recipe) might that be on topic?

Comment: @Megha Not really.  See [What types of recipe questions are allowed?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/728/42797)  for some discussion. BTW, the book in the picture is an actual history book, not a cookbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like a minimal *tartelette au fraise* (little strawberry tart).  These usually have a custard layer and are normally completely covered in strawberries, but I have seen them with far fewer strawberries.  Mixed fruit (*tartelette au fruit*) or raspberry (*tartelette au framboise*) tarts are also common.

Here's a [youtube recipe video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UodCMbfk7G0) (not my favourite recipe format!) of tartelette au fraise with lots of custard and a single strawberry. The crème diplomate used here is similar to crème patissiere but with [whipped cream and gelatine](https://thecottageloaf.com/2016/11/05/creme-diplomate/) added.  I've found a few similar pictures, and the versions with more custard and less strawberry seem to be more popular these days among North-African French chefs than in the bits of France I'm familiar with.  My French is passable but my Arabic is sadly lacking so I can't get as much history from the recipes as I would like.

The pâte brisée/shortcrust pastry case may be sweet or plain (even slightly salted).

As the book in question is an 1960s English translation I suspect tracking down the source image will be tricky, but 1950s/60s French books on patisserie would be an interesting place to look - though I wouldn't expect them to have many colour photos.

Comment: I've also found a pdf of the book but there's no photo credit (and no back cover).  Tineye and Google image search don't find the photo if I crop out the title.